# How to change the PersistenceManager of an attached object?

Tags: jdo, datanucleus, persistence-manager

Assume I have 3 different classes, `A`, `B` & `C`. `C` is designed to have a list of `A`s and `B`s.

If load a list of `A`s and `B`s and keep them **attached**, how can I set them as lists in a **transient** `C` object and persisting the **transient** object ?

The problem is that each of `A`s and `B`s lists are managed by different **PersistenceManagers**. So if I try to persist a **transient** `C` object with a list of `A`s (**attached**, managed by a **PersistenceManager**) and a list of `B`s (**attached**, managed by a second **PersistenceManager**), I'll get an exception saying that the `A`s and `B`s are being managed by a different **PersistenceManager**.

Is there an efficient way to resolve this instead of having to reload all the lists again by the one **PersistenceManager** responsible for persisting the `C` object ?

Comment: errm, you attach them in the same persistence context as you want to use them in. no idea why you'd be playing around with multiple persistence contexts

Comment: I have a service specialized in representing `A` objects to the user (HTML select element) and automatically decodes the submitted value (ie. ID) to a Java object which is still attached so the editing process is managed easily. If JDO doesn't support this then I'll just have to implement another service that returns detached objects instead. But I think this is a lot of work done only to link an object to another. They both must be attached and loaded with the same PM. Is that the only way to do this ?

Comment: If two objects are related and need attaching then clearly they must be attached using the same PM. Or you attach one without the relation, then when attaching the other you relate it to the already attached other object. Can't see what other requirement there is